# Laravel multipl Model linking not working

Tags: php, laravel, web

I have got 3 models: User, Sensor, Data;
Each user can have multiple sensors and each sensor can have multiple data.
I'm new to laravel, but this code seems logical to me but it's not working.

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function sensors() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Sensor');
    }
}
```

```
class Sensor extends Model
{
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function datas(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Data');
    }
}
```

```
class Data extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'datas';

    public function sensor() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Sensor');
    }
}
```

Comment: What is not working ? what errors do you get ? paste your migrations and your code.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what "is not working"? there is no code here attempting to use any of these related models and the code seems logical, but it depends upon how you have setup the tables

Comment: If you're using Laravel 8, the models are now in the App\Models directory/namespace

Comment: I am using Laravel 7.24 but actually today it is working without any kind of change since yesterday. Can anyone explain this, is there any particular reason?